# Copying data frame to matrix based on columns of the data frame

Tags: r, matrix

Task: Copying a column, say "column3" from a data frame to a matrix.

I have a data frame with 4 columns, which is unordered - it looks as below

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
  2       1       3       55555555 
  4       4       4       55555555
  1       3       5       55555555
  3       2       2       55555555
```

Now, I have a matrix of size say 4X4 - called "uI" matrix

What I am trying to achieve is, filling column3 as my data to the above matrix based on column1 (row of a matrix) and column2 (column of the matrix)

Comment: If you have some commentary about your question that isn't part of the question itself, you can put it in the comments down here. On this site, it's preferred that no extra chatter appears in the posts themselves. To see the edits I made, click the "edited" link just below your post.

Comment: @Pratheek16 It is better to use `dput` to show the example data so that we get the structure of the dataset.  Anyway, based on the examples I used for testing, it is not giving any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the row/column indexing by either `cbind` the 'column1' and 'column2' of the dataset ('df1') or convert the first two columns of 'data.frame' (if it is) to `matrix`, get the elements of 'uI' based on that and assign it to the third column of the dataset 'df1'.

```
uI[as.matrix(df1[1:2])] <- df1[,3]
uI
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    0    5    0
#[2,]    3    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    2    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(column1 = c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), column2 = c(1L,
4L, 
3L, 2L), column3 = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 2L), column4 = c(55555555L, 
55555555L, 55555555L, 55555555L)), .Names = c("column1", "column2", 
"column3", "column4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
uI <- matrix(0, 4, 4)
```

Comment: I tried the above and I get an error as below, Error in "column1":"column2" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.frame`(df1, "column1":"column2") :
  NAs introduced by coercion                                                                             2: In `[.data.frame`(df1, "column1":"column2") :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: @Pratheek16  I updated with the data used.  It is not showing any error.

Comment: akrun - I tried the same data as above and I still get the error message as mentioned in the previous comment. It would be great if you could show me step wise - I just created a data frame and a matrix as above and incorporated the code uI[as.matrix(df1[1:2])] <- df1[,3] .

Comment: @Pratheek16  It is strange that you are getting error with the data I showed.  I am using `R 3.2.2.`  Which version of R you have?  Please check if you have `factor` columns or not.

Comment: akrun -I am using 3.2.0.                                                                               df1 <- structure(list(column1 = c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), column2 = c(1L,
4L, 3L, 2L), column3 = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 2L), column4 = c(55555555L, 
55555555L, 55555555L, 55555555L)), .Names = c("column1", "column2", 
"column3", "column4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
 uI <- matrix(0, 4, 4)                                      uI[as.matrix(df1["column1":"column2"])] <- df1[,"column3"], I get the error after executing this statement.

Comment: akrun - I found the mistake, I used data frame column names as indexing parameters in the statement uI[as.matrix(df1[1:2])] <- df1[,3]. I could generate the result you showed above. Please, it would be great if you could explain why it did not work as I did. Thank for the help!

Comment: @Pratheek16  There is a typo with an extra `1`..  It should be `ul[as.matrix(df1[c('column1', 'column2')])] <- df1[, 'column3']`